# Return the id (auto increment) of an inserted line

Tags: php, mysql

1. I insert data into a table called 'roster'. The first column (id_roster) is an id using mysql auto-increment.
2. I run a SELECT to find the id_roster
3. I use this id_roster to insert it into a table 'roster_par_membre' along with other data

   ```
   if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `roster`(`nom_roster`, `description_roster`, `id_organisation`, `created_by`, `creation_date`,`modified_by`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

       $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssiisi', $roster_name, $description_roster, $organisation_id, $user_id, $creation_date, $user_id);

       if (!$insert_stmt->execute()) {
               $reponse = 'Sorry, a database error occurred; please try later';
           } else {
               // if INSERT OK -> create a new line in roster_membre table
                   //1. get the roster_id
                   $sql = "SELECT r.id_roster 
                               FROM roster r
                               WHERE r.nom_roster = ?
                               LIMIT 1";
                   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

                       if ($stmt) {
                           $stmt->bind_param('s', $roster_name); 
                           $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
                           $stmt->store_result();
                           $stmt->bind_result($id_roster);
                           $stmt->fetch(); 

                           $level = 1;
                       //2. create a line with the roster_id and insert the membre as level 1 
                           $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `roster_par_membre`(`id_membre`, `id_roster`, `level`, `modified_by`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                           $insert_stmt->bind_param('iiii', $user_id, $id_roster, $level, $user_id);
                           $insert_stmt->execute();

                       $reponse = 'success';
                       }
   ```

So far the code is working but it is not very nice.
Is there a way when we create a new line in a table to directly return a value (id with auto-increment) to be used in a sql query (to insert data into a second table)? or maybe to merge the two query (the two INSERT) in one statment?

short edit: it is an AJAX $response the return value (JSON)

Comment: Looking for last_insert_id?

Comment: what about using just mysqli->query(insert) , mysqli->insert_id?

Comment: @vp_arth yes that exactly that  last_insert_id; I will check. Any idea on how can I modify my code accordingly?

Comment: @Raphael_b, I have good idea - you should open it in your code editor and modify your code.

Comment: @albanx: thanks for the tip. I am currently looking at this option. It seems to be what I was looking for. just need to find how to make it work. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,solution:

```
                //1. get the roster_id
            $sql = "SELECT r.id_roster 
                        FROM roster r
                        WHERE r.nom_roster = ?
                        LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

                if ($stmt) {
                    $stmt->bind_param('s', $roster_name); 
                    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($id_roster);
                    $stmt->fetch();
```

Just need to replace all this part by

```
$id_roster =  $mysqli->insert_id;
```

nice and easy. THANKS to albanx

Comment: That is ok. I just post some examples short hands functions that I use for writing queries faster.

Answer (score 0):

these are the functions I used for query on projects that I do not want to use any framework (just php):

```
/**
     * 
     * Executes query methods
     * @param string $query the query string
     * @param array $vals array of values
     * @param bool $show show the query
     * @return int/array/false
     */
    function q($query, $vals=array(), $show_query=false) 
    {
        $conn = new mysqli(...)
        $offset = 0;
        foreach ($vals as $v) 
        {
            $cv     = $conn->real_escape_string($v);//escape the value for avoiding sql injection
            $fv     = ($v===NULL) ? 'NULL':"'".$cv."'"; //if value is null then insert NULL in db
            $qpos   = strpos($query, '?', $offset);//replace the ? with the valeue
            $query  = substr($query, 0, $qpos).$fv.substr($query, $qpos+1);
            $offset = $qpos+strlen($cv)+1;
        }

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if($show || $result===false) echo $query."<br>";
        $rows = array();
        if($result===true)
        {
            return $conn->affected_rows;
        }
        else if($result===false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) 
            {
                $rows[]=$row;
            }
        }

        return $rows;
    }

    function lastid()
    {
        return $this->qval("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    }
```

Usage example:

```
q('INSERT INTO USER(name, email) VALUES(?,?)', array('admin','admin@admin.com'));
$id = lastid();
```

Comment: I have done some manual escaping here, but this can be adapted to used with mysqli->prepare

Comment: So u open a connection for every query and u inject the raw php value into whats looks a prepared statement and then u abuse the system by injection the values into the `?` ...

Comment: @DarkBee actually this is not the full class, is just an example, as I said can be adapted. And what's the problem escaping and using ? and inject raw php value?

Comment: @DarkBee and do you think (by the way YOU and not u) opening closing connection makes any difference?

Comment: If you run 1000 queries with 1000 users it Does make a difference yes and u should use prepared statements, not inject values yourself

Comment: I do not think so, it does not make any difference, connection are managed by mysql, 1000 users means 1000 different session runs, with separete connections

Comment: One connection per client is more than enough. U should open one connection and pass this connection throughout your factory classes. There is a limit on how many connection u can open on your server [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

Comment: I know perfeclty that there is a limit, and always is done one connection per client, but how can I connect to mysqli(...) is there any "..." connection